# Ошибка ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE при загрузке содержимого веб-страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, get

Я разрабатываю веб-приложение, используя js, POST запросы jquery ajax к серверу (php+MYSQL). Разработка идёт на техническом домене на хостинге jino. Своего домена пока нет. С одного дня, внезапно, у меня стала возникать ошибка при проведении ajax запросов.

`POST http://техническийдомен/директория/file.php net::ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE`,
которая вылезала раз в несколько запросов. Иногда не подгружаются и элементы
страницы, например `GET http://техническийдомен/директория/style.css net::ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE`.

Проблема точно не в коде, так как откат на версию днём ранее, когда ошибки не было, не помогает.

Проверял в разных браузерах (Opera, Chrome, Firefox), везде ошибки существуют. В Google нашёл единственную статью на эту тему: [Unsecure websites net::ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE error](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/49963758?hl=en), но там говорится только про Chrome определённой версии, а у меня, повторяюсь, ошибка в любых браузерах.

С чем это может быть связано и как это решить?

Comment: Смотрите логи запросов на сервере, думаю там будет больше данных по поводу вашей ошибки.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, а как сервер может прислать в браузер ошибку о том, что его порт уже кто-то использует? Если только он не пытается зачем-то второй сервер запустить и проксировать запрос к нему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, разобрался сам. Опытным путём убедился, что ошибки возникают только на моём устройстве. После удаления приложения, установленного в день, когда стала выскакивать ошибка, все ошибки полностью исчезли.
Вызывало ошибки приложение Chess assistant 20 Pro, скачанное с торрента.